# Solution to Python for Everybody exercise 6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indexing

I'm currently following the free PY4E course and going through the exercises one by one to get a good understanding of the basics. I got stuck understanding the outcome of the following exercise:

*"Write a while loop that starts at the last character in the string and works its way backwards to the first character in the string, printing each letter on a separate line, except backwards."*

My program:

```
fruit = "apple"
index = -1
while index < len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter)
    index = index - 1
```

The program prints 'apple' backwards as expected but ends with a traceback: string index out of range.

Why is this and how would one prevent the traceback from happening for this particular exercise?

I've tried adjusting the index, and index > len(fruit) but in the latter case there is no result printed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ask your self what is the value of `index` in each iteration of the loop, and what is the value of `len(fruit)` ? How do these values compare?

Comment: I think for this exercise you should use non-negative indices. What would be the index of the last character, what is the one of the first character?

Comment: A negative index is always going to be *less than* a positive length. Consider: `while abs(index) <= len(fruit):` More importantly is learning how to discover this issue on your own. Printing relevant variables would help illuminate: `print(letter, index, len(fruit))` so you can see what's happening inside your iterations.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using indices: you can loop through the individual characters of a string directly; also backwards. Then again, for that, you'd be using a for loop, not a while loop, so I find the exercise somewhat odd, if not unPythonic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insightful comments! Helps me understanding this issue a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` will always be less than the length of `fruit`. So once your script reaches an index of `-6` it is throwing the error because it exceeds the length of the string `apple`. Another way to accomplish your task would be:

```
fruit = "apple"

for letter in fruit[::-1]:
    print(letter)
```

In Python you can slice strings like an array. [string[start:stop:step]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-slicing-in-python/#). In this example, `[::-1]` is saying from start to end in -1 steps aka from the end to the start.

If you want to keep what you have you can fix it by:

```
fruit = "apple"
index = 1
while index <= len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[-index]
    print(letter)
    index += 1
```

Each iteration of the loop is doing:

```
fruit[-1] = e
fruit[-2] = l
fruit[-3] = p
fruit[-4] = p
fruit[-5] = a
```

Comment: `for letter in reversed(fruit):` might even be considered clearer in this case: it's explicit you're looping over the reverse of `fruit`.

Comment: I agree I would go with that too.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow, thanks a lot! I think I get how it works now.